# Why is scipy's curve_fit providing a different parameter estimation than my TI-84's regression calculator?

Tags: python, regression, calculator, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize

I am doing a power-law best fit of some data,

```
xdat = [0.117, 0.241, 0.782, 0.734, 1.275, 1.192, 1.483, 0.131, 0.279, 0.453, 1.128, 0.928, 2.197]
ydat = [260.07, 85.82, 87.71, 124.57, 32.35, 80.5, 31.86, 55.36, 44.8, 27.28, 51.21, 53.77, 43.58]
```

and scipy.optimize's curve_fit function

```
def powlaw(x,a,b):
  return a*(x**b)

popt, pcov = curve_fit(powlaw, xdat, ydat)
```

provides the following results:

```
>>> popt
array([51.96762158, -0.4920125 ])
```

corresponding to y ~ 52 x<sup>-0.49</sup>.

Meanwhile, my TI-84 (Plus C Silver Edition) calculator's `PwrReg` function gives:

```
y=a*x^b
a=52.23979898
b=-.308726274
```

corresponding to y ~ 52 x<sup>-0.31</sup>.

The slight coefficient difference is acceptable for my purposes, but that exponent discrepancy definitely isn't.
Any ideas?

Comment: Which fit has a smaller MSE?

Comment: visually both solutions provide a reasonable fit, I guess that both optimizer use different cost functions, thats the reason for different results.

Comment: It matters less why they're different; it matters more which one serves your case better. What is the real-world source of these data? Are all values of the random variable equally important to fit?

Comment: Checking the numbers, the MSE of scipy's fit (~31614) is smaller than the TI-84's fit (~36574), so the scipy fit is arguably better, though there are other metrics to check. As to why they are different, scipy uses least-squares, but the TI-84 might be prioritizing something else. Or, the TI-84 might perform fewer iterations and therefore doesn't achieve as good of a fit. It is impossible to say without seeing the source code.

Comment: @jared It would usually be impossible, but a lucky guess shows us that they're almost certainly doing a log fit (which is reasonable for a dedicated `PwrReg` function).

Answer (score 0):

The immediate "why" is because TI is performing a log-error fit instead of a lin-error fit:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

xdat = np.array([0.117, 0.241, 0.782, 0.734, 1.275, 1.192, 1.483, 0.131, 0.279, 0.453, 1.128, 0.928, 2.197])
ydat = np.array([260.07, 85.82, 87.71, 124.57, 32.35, 80.5, 31.86, 55.36, 44.8, 27.28, 51.21, 53.77, 43.58])
order = xdat.argsort()
xdat = xdat[order]
ydat = ydat[order]


def powlaw(x: np.ndarray, a: float, b: float) -> np.ndarray:
    return a * x**b


def powlaw_log(x: np.ndarray, a: float, b: float) -> np.ndarray:
    return np.log(a) + b*np.log(x)


popt_lin, _ = curve_fit(
    f=powlaw, xdata=xdat, ydata=ydat,
)
popt_log, _ = curve_fit(
    f=powlaw_log, xdata=xdat, ydata=np.log(ydat),
)
popt_ti = 52.23979898, -.308726274

ax: plt.Axes
right: plt.Axes
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

ax.plot(xdat, ydat, label='Experiment')
ax.plot(xdat, powlaw(xdat, *popt_lin), label='Fit lin')
ax.plot(xdat, powlaw(xdat, *popt_log), label='Fit log')
ax.plot(xdat, powlaw(xdat, *popt_ti), label='Fit TI', linestyle='dashed')
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: fit]

But since your data don't vary massively in range (even though this is a power function), there's no clear winner. If you had multiple orders of magnitude that would be a different story.

Comment: I was going to post my own solution once I figured out what they were doing, but you beat me to it. Instead, I'll link the [TI84 Plus C Silver Edition manual](https://education.ti.com/en/guidebook/details/en/1743A58846484D5C9C6E1525B2548EED/ti-84-plus-c-silver-edition-guidebook), which says on page 203 (PDF page 210) that they are fitting the "linearly transformed data." And as per the [TI36x Pro manual](https://education.ti.com/en/guidebook/details/en/858D1A4A484E493DBA150F4F3BD1DC9D/36xpro) (page 37), it is a least-squares fit.